# Making a second page on a menucard

Tags: jquery, css, menu, multipage

this is my first question here and i try to make it as clear as possible.

I have a 2-page menucard that can open and close.
Now i'm trying to make a second page in it, so you can 'turn' the page once more.

[DEMO](http://digitusweb.nl/menukaart/)

when you click 'open menucard',  3 buttons will pop up on the top-right.
when you click 'next' the next 2 pages should pop-up, and when clicking 'prev' these 2 pages should be removed and show the normal.
But when you click close, all pages should close.

I hope it can be a simple add-on, any help/input is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It starts here

```
$open = $cover.find('a.rm-button-open'),
```

and this is the button that must be clicked for the page to turn

```
<a href="#" class="rm-button-open">View the Menu</a>
```

This is the click event code

```
$open.on( 'click', function( event ) {

                openMenu();
                return false;

            } );
```

This is the `openMenu()` function

```
openMenu = function() {

            $container.addClass( 'rm-open' );

        },
```

Where you want to put this `<a href="#" class="rm-button-open">View the Menu</a>` to enable one go to the next page is up to you.

Comment: Hey thanks @Albus for answering, that was the side of the code that was clear to me, but i meant, once it's open, it has 2 pages. But when you click 'next' the right page should turn, to make 2 more pages come up. Thats what i'm goaling to.

Comment: You will need to add more html to the page for the next and previous.

Comment: Well, yeah i figured that out too haha, but i'm not really a coding expert, thats why i'm asking here. Maybe people can give me some answers.. as in: what html,css & jquery should be added and where..